# Django database queries per view in APIs

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-orm, database-performance

So I have been developing a Django server application that mostly works as an API endpoint for a mobile app, with about 30 different models, almost all of them having FKs to each other or other or being in MTM relationships. Now that we're going into production (but do not yet have a lot of users), I have noticed (using [Silk](https://github.com/jazzband/silk)) that the most complex query that fetches a bunch of objects as JSON makes about 500 SQL queries (and those objects each have about 5 FKs and 2 MTMs, which are all fetched as object fields in the JSON). The numbers don't seem to be too huge (as 50k qps seems to be a normal number for Postgres, which we are using as our DBMS), but I am getting worried about the future. Are those numbers normal in early production? What is the normal distribution of database requests per view for an API like the one I described? We are not currently using [DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework), but I am looking towards it. Does it solve this problem?

Comment: No, it's not normal; and no, DRF won't help at all. You need to look into what the queries actually are, and use optimisations like select_related and prefetch_related to help.

Comment: In most cases just adding a few (maybe even 2 or 3) `select_related` or `prefetch_related` statements can reduce the amount of queries from 500 to 10. You will most likely see many very similar queries in the logs which should help you identify which statement is the culprit.